# Fontawesome always reloading icons

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I upgraded from Fontawesome 3 to Fontawesome 5.
Now I got several problems. If I am just linking the font-awesome.min.css in the head, the icons are not loading. I just see squares.
If I link the all.css and tha all.js in the head, I works. So the icons are shown correctly. But everytime, I am clicking any Button and the page is realoding, it takes around half a second to reload the icons. In the previous Version it worked without the js and the icons weren't reloading at all.
I am not sure why it is behaving like this. Maybe because all the <i ...> are converted into svg?

Do you have any hints what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

The class names changed.

In FontAwesome 3:

```
<i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i>
```

In FontAwesome 5:

```
<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
```

You should look them up [here](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons) and change them manually.

Comment: I changed some classnames to the correct ones, but that didn't do anything

Comment: @John9211 did you remove links to the previous version? The minified one should work as well.

Comment: Yes, deleted all old stuff from version 3

Comment: The squares are there because the icon font didn't load properly. @John9211 Can you provide the code or link to the page?